# Linear output layer back propagation

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation, linear-regression

So I'm stack to something that it's probably very easy but I can't get my head around it. I'm building a Neural Network that will consist of many layers with non-linear activation functions (probably ReLUs) and the last output layer will be linear because we are trying to catch a specific number and not a probability. I've done the forward propagation calculations but I'm stuck at the back propagation ones.

Let's say that I'm gonna use the cross entropy loss function: (we will implement the MSE as well)   $-(y \log (a)+(1-y) \log (1-a))$. (I understand that this is not a good option for a regression problem)

So we can easily find the dJ/dA $d A=\frac{\partial J}{\partial A}=-\left(\frac{y}{A}-\frac{1-y}{1-A}\right)$ of the last layer and we can start going backwards finding the $\frac{\partial J}{\partial Z^{[L]}}$ which we can calculate from the equation: $d Z^{[L]}=d A*g^{\prime}\left(Z^{[L]}\right)$ The problem lies at the second part of this equation where the derivative of g is.

What will be the outcome since we have a linear activation function which derivative is equal with 1? (Activation function: f(x) = x, f'(x) = 1)

Will it be an identity matrix with the shape of Z[L] or a matrix full of ones with the same shape again? I'm asking about the term $g^{\prime}\left(Z^{[L]}\right)$.

Many thanks.

Comment: You don't want to implement cross entropy loss with linear activation. The cross entropy loss function is poorly defined when inputs are less than 0 or greated than 1. It can be done though, so if you are still interested in the theory, can you please specify in more detail what the loss function is - give a formula, because there are a couple of variations that are called "cross entropy".

Comment: You can use LaTex between `$` signs e.g. `$\nabla_{Z^{[L]}} = \frac{\partial J}{\partial Z^{[L]}}$` becomes $\nabla_{Z^{[L]}} J = \frac{\partial J}{\partial Z^{[L]}}$. I suggest you do this in the question to make it easier to read. Use [edit] link to alter the question. Also, can you be more specific about what "the second part of this equation" refers to - say which term you mean? Also be clear about "outcome" - are you asking about the overall loss value, or just the value of the term yo uare having trouble with?

Comment: I just edited the post. You can have a second read now. Many thanks.

Comment: Can you please put your main question in the title? Right now, your title is not a question and it's not very descriptive.